# Using COPY FROM STDIN in a stored function

Tags: postgresql, stdin, plpgsql

I'm trying to copy data into a table from a stored PostgreSQL function. The data of rows and the table name are received from a java program and the part that causes errors is this one:

```
_copyquery := FORMAT('COPY %s FROM STDIN (DELIMITER ''|'', FORMAT CSV); %s \.', _tablename, _stdin);
execute _copyquery;
```

Where the _tablename is the name of the table and the _stdin are the rows of data formatted as such:

```
12|34|139901177705664|1545226308991|991389|1545226308991|1545226308991|0|0|0|0|0|0|000|0.0.0.0|0.0.0.0|2328620776|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0.0.0.0|0.0.0.0|0|0|0|0||0|0|0|-|0|0|0|0|0|195.46.227.124|33840|10.110.186.41|2123|2|0|3090304976|0.0.0.0|::|0|||0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|2|5
```

The error I get is :

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "12"

where the "12" is always the first field, most commonly 12 or 3.
Any ideas why this isn't working out?

Comment: That won't work, it will try to parse the copy data as SQL statement. I don't think you can use `COPY ... FROM STDIN` in a PostgreSQL function. Last time I looked, the JDBC driver had no support for `COPY` at all.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was afraid this was the case while reading some other issues but the postgresql documentation on copy makes it look like this will work perfectly. Any ideas to alternatives for loading huge amounts of rows into a single table using what I have now? One thing would be writing these rows to a file and using copy afterwards but this is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: The simple solution would be `INSERT` statrments. If you use prepared statements and run all inserts in a single transaction, it should be reasonably fast.

Comment: Do you really need to do that from the plpgsql function? If you are ok to invoke copy directly from java than there is a way to do that.

Comment: In my experience insert statements are very much slower especially how many rows I'm inserting at a time. I'm implementing a solution using CopyManager in java. It just seemed more clean and safe for me to do everything in the stored procedure.

Comment: I'm afraid `COPY FROM` can only copy either from stdin or from file. You can't access stdin of the postgres process from the function. So the other option is to prepare a file (which should reside on the server filesystem) and copy it. Note that plpgsql can't write to files on server. To overcome this you can use some untrusted language like pl/python. So solution with `CopyManager` is cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out that my request is currently impossible to do and have settled on using the [CopyManager](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/copy/CopyManager.html) to insert data programmatically. Keep in mind with the volumes of data I was working with insert statements would be way to slow and this is a good solution.